# How do I pass arguments from command line to the python script to read and update values of certain keys present in a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, argparse

I have certain data in a json file (say, example.json),

**example.json**

```
data = {
     'name'   :  'Williams',
     'working':  False,
     'college':  ['NYU','SU','OU'],
     'NYU'    :  {
                  'student'  : True,
                  'professor': False,
                  'years'    : {
                                 'fresher'  : '1',
                                 'sophomore': '2',
                                 'final'    : '3'

                                }

                   }
   }
```

I wish to write a code wherein I can give the arguments on Command line, i.e. suppose if a script is saved in a file 'script.py', then,

In the terminal: If I enter `*$ python3* script.py --get name --get NYU.student` Then it outputs `name=Williams`

`NYU.student=True`

If I enter `*$ python3* script.py' --set name=Tom --set NYU.student=False`

Then, it updates name and NYU.student keys in the dictionay to Tom and False and outputs `NYU.student=Tom` and `NYU.student=False` on the command line.

I have tried the following code for the python script (i.e. script.py)

**script.py**

```
import json
import pprint
import argparse


    if __name__== "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--get", help="first command")
    parser.add_argument("--set", help="second command")


    args=parser.parse_args()

    with open('example.json','r') as read_file:
        data=json.load(read_file)
    



    if args.set == None:
        key = ' '.join(args.get[:])
        path = key.split('.')
        now = data
        for k in path:
          if k in now:
            now = now[k]
          else:
            print('Error: Invalid Key')
        print(now)  
    elif args.get == Null:
        key, value = ' '.join(args.set[:]).split('=')
        path = key.split('.')
        now = data
        for k in path[:-1]:
            if k in now:
                now = now[k]
            else:
                print('Error: Invalid Key')
        now[path[-1]] = value



    with open('example.json','w') as write_file:    #To write the updated data back to the same file
            json.dump(data,write_file,indent=2)
```

However, my script is not working as I expect it to? Kindly, help me with the script

Comment: Please explain how it is not working, or what errors you get when you run it.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, however it is not displaying the read values or the updated values on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following issues:

1. When joining the argument values in line number 23 and 35, you use a space. This leads to the "Error key" value. Removing the space will solve the issue.

```
key = ''.join(arg[:])
```

2. You defined the arguments to only pass one value. Not multiple. Therefore even if you pass multiple `--get` or `--set` values, the script only gets one value. Adding `action="append"` to line number 9 and 10 will solve the issue.

```
parser.add_argument("--get", help="first command", action="append")
parser.add_argument("--set", help="second command", action="append")
```

Full code:

```
import json
import pprint
import argparse


if __name__== "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--get", help="first command", action="append")
    parser.add_argument("--set", help="second command", action="append")


    args=parser.parse_args()
    try:
        with open('example.json','r') as read_file:
            data=json.load(read_file)
    except IOError:
        print("ERROR: File not found")
        exit()
    
    if args.set == None:
        for arg in args.get:
            
            key = ''.join(arg[:])
            
            path = key.split('.')
            now = data
            for k in path:
              if k in now:
                now = now[k]
              else:
                print('Error: Invalid Key')
            print(f"{arg} = {now}")  
    elif args.get == None:
        for arg in args.set:
            key, value = ''.join(arg[:]).split('=')
            
            path = key.split('.')
            now = data
            for k in path[:-1]:
                if k in now:
                    now = now[k]
                else:
                    print('Error: Invalid Key')
            print(f"{arg}")
            now[path[-1]] = value
            



    with open('example.json','w') as write_file:    #To write the updated data back to the same file
            json.dump(data,write_file,indent=2)
```

Comment: How do I print the set value as well? Suppose if I enter <python3 --set name=Tom>, then I need to get output <name=Tom> on the command line, so that I can confirm that it has been set.

Comment: add a `print(f"{arg} = {now}")` like this.

Comment: And how do I handle if  I am unable to open example.json file, i.e. I want to print a message 'ERROR: File not found', if the file example.json is not present or cannot be opened.

Comment: You can use a Try except block for that. I have updated my code. Please check. Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Comment: There seems to be sometype of error in the line <print(f"{arg}")>, the second last line of elif block

Comment: @Insuzu f-strings was a later addition to python.  what version are you running?

Comment: @RufusVs 3.8 version of python

Comment: @ Harshana Serasinghe  How do I error out properly if anything other than (set or get) has been used?  How do I handle the exception if some negative cases are encountered, suppose I use <--get fullname>, then I want a user defined error rather than program itself erroring out since, there is no key as 'fullname' in the JSON file.

Comment: In your script, you already use a `print()` statement when the key is invalid. I think you can use it for that purpose

Comment: When I do, python3 script.py --set abc.xyz (Note: This is not the proper key and there is no '=') . I get, Traceback (most recent call last): File "script.py" , line <> in <module>  ,     key, value = ' '.join(arg[:]).split('='),      ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).     I want to handle this error.

Comment: Even though someone uses, --set abc.xyz , the control goes to the elif block handling this update operation and errors out from this line, key, value = ' '.join(arg[:]).split('='). Is there any way by which the command --set abc.xyz  doesnot get parsed because there is no '=' sign in the command.

Comment: Use Try except block with `ValueError` as the exception, Example: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 1):

here is the get part of the question, I hope that you can continue the set part of your assignment. good luck

`python test.py --get name NYU.student`

```py
import json
import pprint
import argparse

def match(data: dict, filter: str):
    current = data

    for f in filter.split("."):
        if f not in current:
            return False
        current = current[f]
    
    return current == True
    

if __name__== "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--get", nargs="*", help="first command")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open('example.json','r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    if args.get is not None and len(args.get) == 2:
        attr_name = args.get[0]
        if match(data, args.get[1]):
            print("{}={}".format(attr_name, data[attr_name]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass arguments using command line make use of **sys module in python3**. The sys module reads the command line arguments as a list of strings. The first element in the list is always the name of the file and subsequent elements are arg1, arg2 ..... so on.

Hope the following example helps to understand the usage of sys module.

Example Command :

```
python filename.py 1 thisisargument2 4
```

The corresponding code

```
import sys

# Note that all the command line args will be treated as strings
# Thus type casting will be needed for proper usage

print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
print(sys.argv[3])
```

Corresponding Output

```
filename.py 
1 
thisisargument2 
4
```

Also please make a thorough google search before posting a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: The sys module has nothing to do with this question.   The OP is using the argparse module.  Please understand the question before posting an answer on stackoverflow.